# What is the equivalent of Program.cs in VB.NET

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms

What is the equivalent of Program.cs in VB.NET WinForms application?

I need to move my .CS app to VB.NET.

As I do not have forms in my WinForms project in Program.cs I do the following:

```
Application.Run(new MyForm(parm1, parm2);
```

How to move this code in VB.NET?

Thanks

Comment: Can't understand your anger. I search before and no answer Google gave me was satisfying. @SteveDog cleared all my doubts and helped me make my app running properly.

Comment: One way to avoid complaints like @Ramhound's is to show what you found when searching, and explain why it was not satisfying. Either way, I'm glad you asked, because the answers helped me.

Comment: I agree with Don Kirkby, this question appears on the top when I googled 'vb.net program.cs'.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

By default, VB.NET applications use the mysterious **Windows Application Framework** which means that the build process adds an entry point for you which automatically runs whichever form you use as the main form.  You can access these settings via **Project Properties** > **Application** > **Windows application framework properties**.

If you don't want to use the framework, un-check the **Enable application framework** check box and then select that you want to use `Sub Main` as your **Startup object**.  Then you can create a module with a `Public Sub Main` method which will be the entry point to the application, just like in Program.cs in C#.

Answer (score 10):

It doesn't matter whether it's Program.cs or YouNameIt.cs.

The default entry point is `Main()`.

This code should work, unless you have another entry point (Can be specified in project settings).

```vb
Shared Sub Main()     
   ' Starts the application.
     Application.Run(New Form1())
End Sub
```

Comment: Does this need to be a `Module`? And if so, is the `Shared` keyword redundant?

Answer (score 6):

As [Steven's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10534791/4794) says, by default you don't need anything like `Program.cs` in a VB.NET application. If you want to replace the standard launch code, however, you can add a new module and select it as the startup object.

First, right click on the project and choose Add: Module.... You can name the module anything you like, but I named it Program.vb to be consistent with the C# default. Paste in the following code:

```vb
Module Program
    Public Sub Main()
        Application.Run(New Form1()) ''//Use your main form here
    End Sub
End Module
```

Next, right click on the project and choose Properties. On the Application tab, uncheck "Enable application framework". Then change the startup object to Program. There's another option called Sub Main that I think will run the `Main()` subroutine wherever it is.

Now that you've replaced the standard launch code, you can add other things to your `Main()` subroutine. I noticed one other thing on [MSDN (How to: Change the Startup Object for an Application)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/17k74w0c%28v=vs.100%29.aspx):

> When using a custom Sub Main procedure as the Startup object, code in the application events (`Startup`, `Shutdown`, `StartupNextInstance`, and `UnhandledException`) is not executed.

Comment: Thanks for the extra clarification.  Moving from C# to VB .NET is bound to raise questions like this one.